# What's the best way to integrate video chat into a website?

Tags: video, audio, chat

I want to make video/audio chat(both one-to-one and chatroom) available on my website through web browser, and no download or login required. My back end is php+mysql. What's the available (and free) solutions out there? What are their pros and cons?

Comment: I'm thinking this is more apropos to superuser.com than SO.

Comment: Thanks for your thinking, but i need a solution. Bring it on if you have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [tokbox/opentok](http://www.tokbox.com/) is your answer :)

**Notes :** There is a free version and a premium version. Premium version provides archiving features.

Comment: I looked at it, and their site looks great, and there is a lot of developer support, but when we tried their service, the video and audio quality was really bad. Google Talk video was much better between the same machines. Is tokbox available only in certain regions (we need it to work in Japan and between Japan and the US)?